# Creating a dictionary keeping track of values used

Tags: performance, dictionary, optimization, coding-efficiency

Is there a more efficient way to perform

```py
d2 = {}
t  = []

for ids in dict_dup.keys():
    for val in dict_dup[ids]:   #### the value is a list of ids
        if val not in t:
            t.append(val)
            d2[val] = ids
```

Basically, I want to switch the key and value of my dict_dup, with the rule that if a value is already assigned to neither a key or a value, you can use it, otherwise not.
Since there are duplicates in the values I need to keep track of them to not have 2 identical keys.

The keys are sorted in a particular order (I know the order in which I do impacts the final result).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `tt` is unused in your code. Also making `t` a set should improve membership testing  of `val`.

Comment: You should add the python tag to get answers and remove the recursion tag since there is no recursion involved here as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your tips. tt is unused and I'll remove it. I can also convert t to a set as suggested. 

For the tags, honestly I go to idea what to use!